# Changing between symbolic and textual format of writing currency

Tags: macros, siunitx

I'm looking for a way to switch between symbolic and textual formatting of currency - e.g. $5 vs 5 dollars. Additionally, I want to choose which currency to display and change between currencies as needed.

This is what I had in mind, but maybe there are better solutions. Is there a way to achieve a set-up where any numbers I want displayed as currency I write as `\money{5}`, for example, and then I can change the currency as needed using a command. Something like `\setcurrency[textual]{dollars}` for example? Later, I might want to switch to `\setcurrency[symbolic]{pounds}`.

One challenge is this code would have to know when to use the singular 'dollar' or 'pound'. For describing single units.

Here is a basic MWE of the output I want:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\$1 and \$5.

1 dollar and 5 dollars.

\textsterling1 and \textsterling5.

1 pound and 5 pounds.
\end{document}
```

[image]

And here is a mock-up of the solution I had in mind:

```
% FICTIONAL CODE!
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\setcurrency[symbolic]{dollars}\money{1} and \money{5}.

\setcurrency[textual]{dollars}\money{1} and \money{5}.

\setcurrency[symbolic]{pounds}\money{1} and \money{5}.

\setcurrency[textual]{pounds}\money{1} and \money{5}.
\end{document}
```

Additionally, I like how the `siunitx` package allows you to format the way the number is displayed. If there was a way of including this functionality that would be an added bonus.

I'm only looking for the functionality I've described above. But, I can think of a super-charged version that is able to take `\money{1.35}` with the options `\setcurrency[fulltextual]{euros}`, and return 'one euro and thirty-five cents'. That would be really cool. Maybe a package already exists to do what I'm asking?

Comment: You could check the currency package. Be aware that it currently doesn't work in texlive 2018 due to a bug (https://github.com/antoinelejay/currency/issues/2). There is also the old euro package which allows definitions of currency styles.